# error 424 object required

Tags: vba, excel

Calculator is a tab in the excel file. nnoise is a macro assigned by a cell with a drop-down list. The options of the drop down list is 1,2,3,4 and 5. Based on the selection of the drop-down list, I wish to assign another cell a certain value.

It always appears object required.

```
Sub nnoise()

noiseval = Calculator.Range("E15")

With Calculator

If noiseval = 1 Then
    .Range("F15") = 0

ElseIf noiseval = 2 Then
    .Range("F15") = 30

ElseIf noiseval = 3 Then
    .Range("F15") = 50

ElseIf noiseval = 4 Then
    .Range("F15") = 70

ElseIf noiseval = 5 Then
    .Range("F15") = 90

End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error? What do you mean by "a tab on the Excel file"? Do you mean Calculator is the name of a Worksheet? Or is it a Ribbon tab?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that `noiseval` is coming in as text. Your procedure could also benefit from a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) to replace the `If ... ElseIf ... End If`.

```
Sub nnoise()
    Dim noiseVal As Variant

    With Worksheets("Calculator")
        noiseVal = .Range("E15").Value2

        Select Case noiseVal
            Case 1, "1"
                .Range("F15") = 0
            Case 2, "2"
                .Range("F15") = 30
            Case 3, "3"
                .Range("F15") = 50
            Case 4, "4"
                .Range("F15") = 70
            Case 5, "5"
                .Range("F15") = 90
            Case Else
                .Range("F15") = vbNullString
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

By stacking the comparative values, `noiseVal` is tested against both the string and integer values; e.g. `1` is not equal to `"1"`.

I'm not sure about your worksheet reference; I've assumed from your narrative that **Calculator** is the Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx).